how to use Auth0 with NextJs app running on digitaLOcean app platform
I have the auth0 integration working fine on local but when hosted on the app platform I get  issue below.
I after add the digitalOcean as allowed call back with
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback, https://seahorse-app-ts7rs.ondigitalocean.app/api/auth/callback

I get the below error in the browser log:
error_description: Service not found: http://104.248.162.47:3010/
This is the IP address on the backend API that is called with http://104.248.162.47:3010/api/v1 as the entry point.
